# How can I configurate an installation/package in Chocolatey

Tags: registry, chocolatey

I'm new to **Chocolatey** and playing with it now. My goal is to install and upgrade all my essential applications by one PowerShell script.

I have one problem atm. When I manually install e.g. **CCleaner** then I can configurate by the wizard if I a want a **desktop icon** or if the recycle bin has a new **Run-CCleaner**-entry.
I always disable both of them.

I cannot see a way to configurate my powershell command to disable that two options.

Here is the link to the package: https://chocolatey.org/packages/ccleaner

If there is no option in Chocolately is it recommended that I manipulate the registry in my script after installing CCleaner? How does this work for other apps?

Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, it depends :-(

Some packages, for example [git](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git) allows you to use the concept of [Package Parameters](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-parse-package-parameters-argument#installing-with-package-parameters) to control the different pieces of functionality for an installer.

Now the CCleaner package also has the concept of Package Parameters, but only for specifying the locale that is used for the install.  You can see the available package parameters in the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ccleaner#files).

Now, it is possible to directly pass installation arguments to the native installer.  This is documented here:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-install#options-and-switches

Specifically:

> --ia, --installargs, --installarguments, --install-arguments=VALUE
>        InstallArguments - Install Arguments to pass to the native installer in 
>          the package. Defaults to unspecified.
>
> -o, --override, --overrideargs, --overridearguments, --override-arguments
>        OverrideArguments - Should install arguments be used exclusively without 
>          appending to current package passed arguments? Defaults to false.

Using these arguments on the `choco install` command would allow you, assuming it is possible, to further control the installation.

The hard part would be finding out what arguments needed to be passed to the installer in order for the actions that you want to happen.  There is no standard for this, and it is something that would have to be done on a per package basis.

Comment: "There is no standard for this" - expanding on that, what Gary means is that in Windows there is no standard for installers outside of MSI (and to a degree MSIs as well). It's really a wild west in many respects.